# For doing junit , resource or profile should be used

Tags: spring-boot, junit

In spring boot, we can have many profile: local, dev, qa, prod.
so we need to create a property file for each of them.

if i want to run my junit test locally, do i need to create another property in

src/test/resources or i should use profile for that

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate profile, you can put it in src/main/resources with the rest of your files.

To activate the profile, you could use the following to activate the test profile:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class SpringBootProfileTest {

  @Value("${foo}")
  String foo;

  @Test
  void test(){
    assertThat(foo).isEqualTo("bar");
  }
}
```

Comment: and the difference to have a properties in in src/test/resources ?

Comment: Nothing. For unit testing, the files in main/resources will also be loaded by Spring.
Biggest reason i put them in main/resources: So all the files are closer together and when I add a property, i don't forget to also change it in the application-test.properties.